# useSWR() and mutate() do not behave as expected when component is unmounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swr

I am having an issue with some unexpected behavior with regards to mutate(key). In my data fetching code, I have these hooks/functions:

```js
const recentOptions = {
    refreshInterval: 0,
    revalidateOnFocus: false,
    dedupingInterval: 180000000    //or 500
}

export const useRecent = () => {
    const {data, error} = useSWR(
        `${config.apiUrl}/GetRecentFoundations`,
        getThenResolve,
        recentOptions
    );

    return {
        recent: data,
        isLoading: !error && !data,
        isError: error
    };
}

export const setRecent = async(fid) => {
    await postThenResolve(
        `${config.apiUrl}/SetFoundationRecent`,
        {fid});

    //TODO: So the behavior I am seeing tends to indicate that
    //mutate(key) sends out a message to swr to refetch, but doesn't
    //necessarily cause the cache to be invalidated.
    //This means that mutate will cause any CURRENTLY MOUNTED useSWR()
    //to refetch and re-render, but ones that aren't mounted will
    //return with stale data.
    mutate(`${config.apiUrl}/GetRecentFoundations`);
}
```

I also have a component that fetches data with useRecent():

```js
const FoundationRecents = props => {
    const {recent, isLoading} = useRecent();

    if(isLoading) return <div>...LOADING...</div>;
    if(!recent) return null;

    return <SimpleCard
        titlebg={colors.blue}
        titlefg={colors.white}
        titlesz='small'
        title='Recent'
        contentbg={colors.white}
        component={<FoundationRecentsView recent={recent}/>}
    />
}
```

I use this pattern in two places currently, one where the component is mounted when the `setRecent()` occurs. The other, where the component is unmounted. When the component is mounted, everything works fine. When `mutate()` is called, everything seems to refetch and rerender.

However, if setRecent() is called when the component is unmounted, and I later return to it, I get stale data, and no refetch.

I think I must be misunderstanding what `mutate(key)` does, or maybe I am unclear as to what the `dedupingInterval` is. I thought, that even with a high deduping interval, the mutate would cause the GetRecentFoundations cache to be invalid, and thus the next call to `useSWR()` would require a revalidate.